# Architecture and folder structure to follow in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, architecture, conventions

I have found not much help on this. If I wish to use Backbone.js for a large scale application, what should the folder structure look like? What are the standards/conventions to follow for building the architecture of the project for client-side JS?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718411/backbone-project-organization/26719108#26719108

Comment: take a look to this: https://github.com/daniel-aranda/backbone-bootstrap-2014